# Getting Values from JSON with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I get the following string:

```
[{"Key":1,"Value":"correct"},{"Key":2,"Value":"incorrect"},{"Key":3,"Value":"incorrect"},{"Key":4,"Value":"correct"},{"Key":5,"Value":"incorrect"}]
```

I want to change the background color of my TR based on whether the ID of that TR has a value of "correct" or "incorrect" in the JSON.

How can I get the value of an individual item from JSON?  I have tried:

```
            success: function (result) {
                // update with results
                //alert(JSON.stringify(result));
                //$('#myDiv').html(JSON.stringify(result));

                // non of these work
                alert(result[0]);
                alert(result[key]);
            },
```

Comment: What output do you get ? Or what error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$.each()` to iterate the Array of Objects.

```
$.each(result, function(i, item) {
    alert(item.Key);
});
```

In the callback to `$.each()`, `item` will be a reference to the current item in the Array being iterated.

Then you just use normal property access to get the value for the `Key` property.

---

Of course you could also use a traditional `for` statement to loop the Array.

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    var item = result[i];
    alert(item.Key);
}
```

---

All of this assumes your response has the proper `Content-Type` setting, or you've give `dataType:"json"` to `$.ajax()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your JSON format to Object, in your situation it will be array, so you can use forEach to check what you want.

Try this

```
var obj= JSON.parse( '[{"Key":1,"Value":"correct"},{"Key":2,"Value":"incorrect"},{"Key":3,"Value":"incorrect"},{"Key":4,"Value":"correct"},{"Key":5,"Value":"incorrect"}]' );



obj.forEach(function(i){alert(i.Key);alert(i.Value) })
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this: http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/.I have not used it but looks like and good way to get values from a Json structure.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you specify .. **dataType:'json'** in your Ajax Request

Try

```
alert(result[0]["key"]);  // For the first
```

//

```
$.each(result , function(i) {
    console.log( 'Key is - ' + result[i]["Key"] + ' -- Value is - ' + result[i]["Value"]);
});
```

[Check FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/RXqAm/395/)
​

Comment: I tried using `alert(result[0]["key"]);` and `alert(result[0]["Key"]); ` but it just says, "undefined."

Comment: Try console.log(result)   .. What do you see

Comment: I am rushed so I will have to continue with the working solution of using `$.each` but thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify, but assuming that JSON string is what your ajax code is receiving as the response, then you're actually re-JSONing that text, so it becomes a double-encoded string.

jquery can auto-decode that back to a native structure for you, if you tell is that you're expecting json as a response, e.g.

```
$.ajax({
   dataType: 'json',
   etc...
});
```

then you'd simply have

```
alert(result[0]['key']);
```

or

```
data = jquery.parseJSON(result);
alert(data[0]['key']);
```

Comment: Then the ajax call is failing, and your success code block is never called. add an `error` block to catch that and see why things aren't working.

Comment: No, the success block is called because I am outputting the entire JSON string via `$('#myDiv').html(JSON.stringify(result));`.  The problem is with the code inside of the success block.